How to go about rewriting Node to Hardware Component for ros2_control
I'm currently in the process of rewriting this driver for the Ublox ZedF9P GPS to integrate it into the ros2_control architecture. However, I'm facing challenges due to the complexity of the driver. While there is a guide available on the ROS Control website, I haven't found it particularly helpful thus far.
Our goal is to refactor the driver for seamless integration within the ros2_control architecture. This integration is crucial as we intend to combine the GPS functionality with our IMU (for which I have already developed a Hardware Component for ros2_control) to enable autonomous navigation from point A to point B.
Would you recommend using the existing driver as it is? If so, what would be your rationale? Alternatively, how would you suggest approaching the task of rewriting this intricate driver into a hardware component?
Thank you in advance!

Maybe you have just copied the wrong link, but hardware component guide is here

Finding the hardware component guide is not a problem. However, I find it very challenging to translate the driver mentioned in the question into a hardware component. Therefore, I'm asking how you would approach this task and if you would recommend doing so. Alternatively, would it be worth it to simply use the node that the driver sets up as is?

That depends on your realtime requirements, and if you have a simulation where you can just switch the hardware component. If this is not the case, then there is no argument for writing a hardware component (except for lifecycle etc).

The robot should be capable of autonomous driving using data from the GPS and IMU(which has already been integrated with ros2_control). Regarding the real-time requirements, they should not be too demanding since the robot is expected to drive at approximately 4 km/h.
In terms of simulation, we have a Gazebo simulation set up, but we are not planning to switch GPS modules or other hardware components. At most we would like to turn on/off certain components for testing. Given this, is it correct to assume that you would not see the need to write a hardware component?
